# Dynamic operator in dates inside SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, ssms

I have a stored procedure that makes a insert in a table where the dates are between the actual date minus 1 and the maximum date that already exists in that table:

```
SELECT @DateMax = MAX(Date) FROM Table6

SET @SQLCommand = 'SELECT c.One, e.Two, e.Three, a.Four, d.Five, a.Time
    FROM Table1 a
    INNER JOIN Table2 b ON a.column1 = b.column1
    INNER JOIN Table3 c ON b.column2 = c.column2
    INNER JOIN Table4 d ON a.column3 = d.column3
    INNER JOIN Table5 e ON a.column4 = e.column4
    WHERE a.Time > ' + @DateMax + ' AND a.Time <= ' + GETDATE()-1 + ' '

INSERT INTO Table6 (One, Two, Three, Four, Five, Time)
EXEC sp_executesql @SQLCommand
```

When the SP is runned with the parameter (@Delete) equal a 1 the data is inserted since '2017-01-01' and not from the maximum date from the Table6:

```
IF @Delete= 1
BEGIN 
    DELETE FROM Table6
    SET @DateMax = '2017-01-01'
END
```

The problem is that when the parameter @Delete is equal a 1 then I have to insert all records that are between the '2017-01-01' and the actual date minus 1 but **INCLUDE** the records of the day '2017-01-01' (>=) but if the Delete is equal a 0 then I insert the record between the maximum date of the Table6 and the actual date minus 1 but **NOT INCLUDE** the records with the maximum date of the Table6.

I have a solution that is:

```
IF @DateMax = '2017-01-01'
BEGIN
    SET @Operator = '>='                            
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @Operator = '>'
END
```

And then in the WHERE clause:

```
WHERE a.Time' + @Operator + ' ' + @DateMax + ' AND a.Time <= ' + GETDATE()-1 + ' '
```

But this is ugly, not pretty and not so efficient...

**EDIT:** My question is if there is a better solution to this than the one I did.

Comment: So, what is your question here? You post solutions, and what you've tried but yet you haven't asked anything.

Comment: Edited @Larnu. I post this to try to find new forms to make this without the solution that I made because is not so efficient.

Comment: I think it's far uglier that you're subtracting integers from `GETDATE` instead of using `DATEADD`, but ugliness is in the eye of the beholder. I'm not sure I understand the "not so efficient" part, however. You're dynamically constructing queries, you can have them as efficient as you like -- and going from `>=` to `>` doesn't make the query less efficient. If you want to keep the operator, you can always apply a `DATEADD` to your `@DateMax` constant, and add either 0 or 1, as the case may be.

Comment: I can't see why, in all honesty, you're using dynamic SQL. It doesn't need to be. At least for your first query.

Comment: @JeroenMostert thank you for your suggestion, yes it's more pretty and better that way and I will change to use the `DATEADD`.
@Larnu the query is more extense this is only a example.

Comment: Wow, the table name and field names are all bad. See DateAdd and the Between commands for SQL Server. Also if @Delete = 1 then just set DateMax = '2017-01-01'

Comment: Remember that is not about how "pretty", it's about how readable it is to other people (and the computer).